# How to animate background-size multiple values with anime.js v.3

Tags: background-size, anime.js

I try to animate a border also for IE11 and I thought it will possible through using anime.js.
First I set it up as CSS Animation and try now to translate it to anime.js.
But my problem is that I don't find any example or some in the documentation how I can animate multiple values for background-size.

The div-border should grow animated on the screenborders.

```
const myAnimation = anime({
  targets: '#aniBorder',
  easing: 'linear',
  backgroundSize: [
      {
        duration: 1000,
        value: '+=0 10px, 10px 0, 0 10px, 10px 0';
      },
      {
        duration: 1000,
        value: '+=100% 10px, 10px 0, 0 10px, 10px 0';
      },
      {
        duration: 1000,
        value: '+=100% 10px, 10px 100%, 0 10px, 10px 0';
      },
      {
         duration: 1000,
         value: '+=100% 10px, 10px 100%, 100% 10px, 10px 0';
      },
      {
        duration: 1000,
        value: '+=100% 10px, 10px 100%, 100% 10px, 10px 100%';
      }

  ],
});
```

Here I have a jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/hehukay/edit?html,css,js,output

The rectangle in the middle (`.finishAni`) should show you what I want to realize with anime.js.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make it the same on all platforms would be to use 4 divs instead of one div with an animated border. 4 divs, position: absolute and then position them, appropriately.